# Finding VPNs using scans

Tags: scanner, nmap, scanning

I understand that nmap doesn't know how to recognize some VPN protocols, but I need a way to scan a port and find a result so I know that the port is VPN.

Comment: What results do you want from the scan? Do you only need to know whether the port is open or not, or do you want nmap to extract some information from the openvpn server?

Comment: Have you seen questions like this https://serverfault.com/q/262474/579763 ?

Comment: You're overly optimistic about the data that OpenVPN exposes. The most you can hope for is some TCP/UDP answer that identifies OpenVPN as the listener. See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/262474/how-to-check-that-an-openvpn-server-is-listening-on-a-remote-port-without-using).

Comment: NetBus is a… “remote maintenance tool” (read: trojan) that often used port 12345. That’s why you see this. It is not the result of nmap’s service detection.

Comment: Try to see what you get using `telnet` on the post. Also, you could try the commands in the [above link](https://serverfault.com/questions/262474/how-to-check-that-an-openvpn-server-is-listening-on-a-remote-port-without-using), but adapt them to use TCP.

Comment: That post was from 2011. It seems that since then OpenVPN have stopped giving away that information. This is a logical evolution which improves the security of the server against attacks specifically targeting OpenVPN servers. Any response from the server might have revealed the OpenVPN version of the server and helped in directing the attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN and most VPNs are currently engaged in an "eternal war" with
ISPs and governments seeking to track or block VPN traffic for
maintaining control over internet traffic.
Many countries are now labeling VPNs as a national cybersecurity
threat. Of special note here is the Great Firewall of China (GFW).

This is the reason that the link from 2011 that I have previously
indicated is no longer valid :
[How to check that an OpenVPN server is listening on a remote port without using OpenVPN client?](https://serverfault.com/questions/262474/how-to-check-that-an-openvpn-server-is-listening-on-a-remote-port-without-using?_gl=1*xc8cy6*_ga*OTU2OTY1MzE2LjE1MTg0NDc4OTE.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2NzAzMDY0Mi4xMDIuMS4xNjY3MDMxMzgwLjAuMC4w)

OpenVPN is actively obfuscating its ports and working hard to erase
all traces of its presence.
*This is the reason that it's impossible for you
to identify the port where an OpenVPN server is listening.*

A scientific paper
[OpenVPN is Open to VPN Fingerprinting](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec22-xue-diwen.pdf)
from August 2022 describes a sophisticated attempt to identify
OpenVPN open ports (and makes for quite interesting reading).

The war between the GFW and Tor is a good example of the efforts
now invested in this struggle. This paper says:

> The ongoing arms-race between the GFW and Tor has been extensively
> studied and is most representative of the conflict between censorship
> & surveillance and circumvention tools. Censors started by blocking
> Tor’s website and public relays, which Tor responded to by deploying
> website mirrors and private, unpublished bridges. Next, censors moved
> to blocking with DPI by fingerprinting Tor’s TLS handshake, e.g.
> cipher suites. Tor used Pluggable Transports (PT) obfuscators, such as
> Obfsproxy and meek, to mask the handshake. In response, censors
> deployed active probing to complement DPI-based fingerprinting to
> detect Tor and certain obfuscators.

The paper proposes new methods to identify OpenVPN, although none of
them are (of course) supported by nmap.

Some of the methods are based on the behavior of OpenVPN and the
differences in timing when probing with variously crafted ACK
packages.

In conclusion : OpenVPN itself is now working hard to block you from
identifying its port. It would take a clever program and great
knowledge of OpenVPN to heuristically identify the ports.
All these methods are not within your reach.

In other words, the answer you got : "12345 open", is the most that
you can expect. The "netbus?" part is just an unsuccessful guess
by nmap, as you can see by the question-mark.

Comment: Well, OpenVPN still needs to work as a VPN server but will do its best to avoid a scan, so it will not answer nmap. If you connect to it using the OpenVPN protocol, then it will try to do its job. Many obfuscation methods are aimed at disguising the communications between client and server, so a watcher wouldn't be able to identify an OpenVPN server while it's being used, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Try to adapt [this script](https://vulners.com/nessus/OPENVPN_DETECT.NASL).

Comment: See also [OpenVPN Protocol](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/openvpn-protocol/) for more hints. For more brave measures, the [Source Code](https://openvpn.net/source-code/) is also available.

Answer (score 2):

The port doesn't volunteer what service is running on it.  Technically, the port will be TCP or UDP and a number.  That's it.  The reason why it says NetBus is because it uses a dictionary of common ports and their uses and reports that.  It knows that port 12345 is traditionally (or was) used for NetBus (Wiki below).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBus

Imagine auto-scanning for radio stations.  When one pops up, you know there is a radio station there but you don't know which radio station or what program is on it unless you listen to it.  That's basically what port scanning is: just scanning.  It can find open ports, but it doesn't (and usually can't) determine what is running on it.  It can only make guesses based on previously known info.

Added info...
from https://technical-qa.com/how-does-nmap-know-what-service-is-listening-on-the-various-ports/

> Version detection uses a variety of probes, located in the
> nmap-services-probes file, to solicit responses from the services and
> applications. Nmap queries the target host with the probe information
> and analyzes the response, comparing it against known responses for a
> variety of services, applications, and versions.

Creating a probe might do what you are thinking.  That is probably the extent of what I could offer here.

Also, look at https://nmap.org/book/vscan-fileformat.html

Comment: I don't know if I can answer your question any better.  From https://technical-qa.com/how-does-nmap-know-what-service-is-listening-on-the-various-ports/
Version detection uses a variety of probes, located in the nmap-services-probes file, to solicit responses from the services and applications. Nmap queries the target host with the probe information and analyzes the response, comparing it against known responses for a variety of services, applications, and versions.

Comment: Good answer (+1). @Eladtopaz, you may want to try the `-sV` switch which may give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @rfportilla’s answer, I’d like to draw your attention to the existing [`nmap-service-probes`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmap/nmap/master/nmap-service-probes) file. You’ll find that nmap is indeed set up to detect OpenVPN. There’s a small problem though: It’s in the following (first) section:

```
# This is the NULL probe that just compares any banners given to us
##############################NEXT PROBE##############################
Probe TCP NULL q||
# Wait for at least 6 seconds for data.  It used to be 5, but some
# smtp services have lately been instituting an artificial pause (see
# FEATURE('greet_pause') in Sendmail, for example)
totalwaitms 6000
# If the service closes the connection before 3 seconds, it's probably
# tcpwrapped. Adjust up or down depending on your false-positive rate.
tcpwrappedms 3000
```

It appears OpenVPN is no longer sending a banner on connect OR, going from the linked questions, your OpenVPN instance has TLS authentication activated.

Unless your OpenVPN server sends a recognized banner by itself in the first 6 seconds, the existing OpenVPN service detection will not work.

Nmap does support actively probing the service (sending some sort of dialog). Going from the file, this is usually restricted to certain ports. Further down in the file, the following probes are defined on OpenVPN’s standard port of 1194:

```
##############################NEXT PROBE##############################
# P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2
Probe TCP OpenVPN q|\0\x0e87\xa5&\x08\xa2\x1b\xa0\xb1\0\0\0\0\0|
ports 1194,443,500
rarity 9
match openvpn m|^\0\x1a@........\x01\0\0\0\x007\xa5&\x08\xa2\x1b\xa0\xb1\0\0\0\0$| p/OpenVPN/
# No version info submitted; update to hard match when it's available
softmatch openvpn m|^\0\x1e@........\x02\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x007\xa5&\x08\xa2\x1b\xa0\xb1\0\0\0\0\0\x0e@........\0\0\0\0\0|


##############################NEXT PROBE##############################
# P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2
Probe UDP OpenVPN q|8d\xc1x\x01\xb8\x9b\xcb\x8f\0\0\0\0\0|
ports 1194,443,500
rarity 8
match openvpn m|^@........\x01\0\0\0\0d\xc1x\x01\xb8\x9b\xcb\x8f\0\0\0\0|s p/OpenVPN/
# INVALID-MAJOR-VERSION
softmatch isakmp m|^................\x0b\x10\x05\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\(\0\0\0\x0c\0\0\0\x01\x01\0\0\x05|
```

You are not on port 1194, so these active probes do not “fire”.

Comment: So are you using static TLS authentication or not? This is on top of any other authentication you may have set up. Maybe you should also explain your use case in the question.